# How to initialize SNMP in C

Tags: c, initialization, snmp, agent

Can anyone tell me how to initialize a SNMP agent in c using SNMP library?
The call to "init_agent()" is not working.

I read somewhere that "init_agent()" function should be used before "init_snmp()".
Here is what I am getting while compiling the code:

```
/tmp/ccEiSj2l.o: In function `main':
agent1.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `init_agent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have linked the compiler to snmp library using "-lsnmp".

Comment: The linker is not able to find libsnmp.a, find its location and pass it via the -L flag (something like -L /my/path/to/snmp -lsnmp )

Answer (score 1):

Did you try passing required libraries to your compiler? Try passing  output of the script `net-snmp-config --libs` . (Put back quotes surrounding that command).

Answer (score 0):

I am used to using Net-SNMP for these things, and if you are attempting to create an *agent* with Net-SNMP, then you will need to link against the *agent* library (in addition to whatever other libraries you may be using):

```
-lnetsnmpagent
```